# Is there a precise characterization of “possible rules” on a set?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

I am considering a set of distinct elements, such as

```
a b c d e f
```

and a second set which is an ordering of those elements with repetition, such as:

```
a b b e a c f e b b b a c c
```

I want to ask the intuitive question, is there some “rule” / a *reason* they are ordered this way? And is there a deterministic way to try find out what it is, for any such sequence?

First of all, we can consider the trivial but real case where the “rule” is simply to arrange the elements in exactly that sequence.

If it is not that, then there is some “rule”. But that just opens the question of what a “rule” is/can be, if not just selecting elements one by one / mapping a set of ordinals to the set of symbols.

We have said nothing about the symbols, in terms of relations between each other. But we have not excluded that possibility.

What I worry about is that there is no helpful way to try to test what rule it could be, one by one in order, thoroughly and deterministically (even if a computer had to run for 1 million years to do it).

I think this is because there is no good definition of what a “rule” is. I believe, strictly mathematically, it is going to require the importing / defining of more concepts / structures, from outside the “world” / context of these elements. Because in this “world” so far, there only appears to be ordinals, and one set, and mappings between sets. To assert any other rule than an arbitrary mapping, you need some other “thing” - like an operator, a way for one element to produce another element *inherently*/“by its own logic”. But as far as I understand, algebraically, at the very bottom, every “operator” *is* an “arbitrary mapping” - for example, “addition on the integers” (I think) is really just defined as for each two elements some associated third element, giving a certain “pattern”/structure.

So the sequence can be the result of a complicated sequence of (n-ary) mappings, from some arbitrary starting set, but I am pretty sure we can say that that will comprehensively describe the range of possible rules. The only aspect of the input sets I am not sure about is cardinality, I think that is the only parameter of variation on them right now.

Basically, here is a proof about the cardinality of the set of all mappings between two sets: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_Set_of_All_Mappings/Finite_Sets

I guess the precipice at which I currently stand is if you could hypothetically go through every possible mapping / sequence of mappings, possibly on sets of increasing cardinality? In other words, an ordering?

My thoughts on this are still developing, forgive me if it seems amateur. Can anyone help me understand what field/theory of mathematics I’m actually getting at here - the closest mature mathematical field relevant to this question / this approach?